# How to remove empty strings from elastic search array in all available documents in an index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an array in my elastic search document. Unfortunately, it contains empty strings in some of the documents

It has the following document structure.

```json
{
  "_index" : "products",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "100",
  "_version" : 5,
  "_seq_no" : 4,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "Washing Machine",
    "price" : 49,
    "inStock" : 5,
    "tags" : [
      "electronics",
      "home appliance",
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

I am looking for a query to remove all empty strings from the `tags` array present in all documents in the index.

NB: I am using elastic search 7.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the empty string from your document using an `update_by_query`

```json
POST /products/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{"match_all": {}}],
      "filter": [{"terms": {"tags": [""]}}]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.tags.removeIf(item -> item.isEmpty());",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```